# image uploading using ck

Tags: java, jsp, ckeditor, image-uploading

i need to upload an image to the server using send to server button in ck editor and display the image inthe ckeditor edit area. idone all these things in ckeditor as below,

url : b.config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl following to this code in image.js i set hidden=false; and

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '../ckeditorImage.jsp';
}

ckeditorImage.jsp is like this


try{

    String boundary="";
    String sz="";
    String fname="",sem="",sub="",mod="",empid="";
    Enumeration enum1 = request.getHeaderNames();
    while(enum1.hasMoreElements())
    {
            String header = (String)enum1.nextElement();
            String hvalue = request.getHeader(header);
            if("content-length".equalsIgnoreCase(header) )
        sz=""+hvalue;

    } 
        ServletInputStream sv=request.getInputStream();       
    int ch=0;
    String val="";  
    while((ch=sv.read())!=-1)
    {
        val+=(char)ch;      
                if(val.indexOf("Content-Type: ")>=0)
        {

            String tp="Content-Type: ";

            fname=val.substring(val.indexOf("filename=")+"filename=".length(),val.indexOf(tp));
                        fname=fname.replace('"',' ');
                        System.out.println(" =======fname============    :"+fname);           
            fname="home1.jpg";                  
            long size = fname.length();         

                        while((ch=sv.read())!='\n');
            byte[] b=new byte[Integer.parseInt(sz)];
            int cntr=0;
            while(cntr<b.length)
            {
                b[cntr]=(byte)sv.read();
                cntr++;
            }
                        String str=new String(b);
            int pos=str.indexOf(boundary)-2;
            pos=b.length;
            System.out.println(" =======fname============    :"+fname);  
                         File f=new File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"/images/"+fname);
                         System.out.println(" creation of directory"+config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"/images/"+fname);
                         System.out.println(" creation");
                       /*  if(f.isDirectory())
                         {
                             String fl[]=f.list();

                             for(int i=0;i<fl.length;i++)
                                 {
                                  File fd=new File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"/users/"+sd+"/photos/"+fl[i]);
                                  fd.delete();
                             }
                         }*/
            if(!f.exists())
                f.mkdirs();
                         System.out.println(" creation of directory");
            java.io.FileOutputStream fout=new java.io.FileOutputStream(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"/images/"+fname);

            fout.write(b,2,pos-4);
            System.out.println(" creation of directory"+fout);
            fout.close();
        }
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This project gives you also a filebrowser of CKEditor.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jckconnector/

If you only need the upload part, then look at the servlet code